# Installing SCAP Security Guide for 22.04.1

Tags: apt, 22.04, security

I am unable to install the scap-security-guide on Ubuntu 22.04.1

I followed the documentation on http://static.open-scap.org/ssg-guides/ssg-ubuntu2204-guide-index.html but it shows a package that can not be installed. The site it redirects me to (https://www.open-scap.org/security-policies/scap-security-guide/) asks to perform the install of the following packages for Ubuntu newer than 18.04:

```
apt install ssg-base ssg-debderived ssg-debian ssg-nondebian ssg-applications
```

None of the above packages seem to be available for Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Is there a way I can have the OpenSCAP Security Guide installed on Ubuntu 22.04 systems? Are we compelled to use the usg package to perform Security scans on Ubuntu 22.04 systems?

Answer (score 2):

It's not available on Ubuntu 22.04.1 repositories
but it's an opensource project with means you can download source code and compile profiles [Docs](https://complianceascode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/developer/02_building_complianceascode.html).

```
apt-get install cmake make expat libopenscap8 libxml2-utils ninja-build python3-jinja2 python3-yaml python3-setuptools xsltproc

git clone -b master https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content.git
cd content/build/
cmake ../
make -j4

ls -lah ssg-ubuntu2204*
oscap info ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml
oscap info --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cis_level2_server ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml
 
oscap xccdf eval --results result.xml --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cis_level2_server ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml
oscap xccdf generate report result.xml > report.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Building the Guide and openscap on your machine is certainly possible but can be painful if you don't do that sort of thing every day.  I was in the same boat and needed to test on focal so I did some backports [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Enerdboy/+archive/ubuntu/embedded).  It's much easier to use the PPA than build from source.

Comment: `scap-workbench` installed okay, but `apt install scap-security-guide` results in "E: Unable to locate package scap-security-guide"

Comment: Sorry, the upstream packaging creates install packages with names starting with ssg- and only the source package is called scap-security-guide,  Try installing `ssg-debderived` and see what else it pulls in.